# Python Flask - " Check if the username exists in the MySQL database"

Tags: python, mysql, flask-login

I am running a python Flask application which takes a username and password.  I wanted to check if the username exists on the Mysql database. If it does, I wanted to return " username exists" on the web page.

below is my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml

app = Flask(__name__)

db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']

mysql =MySQL(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.method=='GET':
        #fetch form data
        userdetails = request.form
        name = userdetails['name']
        email = userdetails['email']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        new_value= cur.execute("SELECT (name,email) FROM users where name = %s and email=%s",'name','email')
        if new_value> 0:
            return "the username exists"
        else:
            return "SUCCESS!,Successfully entered into the Database"

    return render_template('index.html')
```

---

when i run the flask application, my web page doesnt return anything.

Comment: `If request.method == ‘POST’ and request.method == ‘GET’` will never be true - request.method can only take one value at a time. Did you mean to put “or” between the two clauses?

Comment: when i run the python application, i see "127.0.0.1 - - [03/Feb/2019 21:23:31] "GET /?name=rick&email=rick%40gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200" . That is the reason behind the 'GET' attribute

Comment: Ok, but I don’t think you read my comment fully - your if condition is always returning false because request.method can not be both ‘POST’ and ‘GET’ simultaneously.

Comment: I edited the code to remove the 'get' and only leave the request.method to 'post'.However, I the web page still don't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i cant comment since i dont have enough reputation however to fetch the form data the `request.method` needs to be `POST` since that is when a user clicks on a button to submit the form. As Brian Driscoll stated, `request.method` can not be both `POST` and `GET` simultaneously, its like saying:

```
if bob.age == 15 and bob.age == 50
```

bob cant be both 15 AND 50 years old at the same time, in the same way `request.method` cant be `POST` AND `GET` at the same time.
so what you want to do is

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        userdetails = request.form
        name = userdetails['name']
        email = userdetails['email']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        new_value= cur.execute("SELECT (name,email) FROM users where name = %s and email=%s",'name','email')
        if new_value> 0:
            return "the username exists"
        else:
            return "SUCCESS!,Successfully entered into the Database"
```

For more info about `POST`, `GET` and other requests you can refer to the article [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm)

Comment: I set the request.method to 'POST'. still the web page don't return anything.

Comment: Can you share your HTML

Comment: @A.Laffir what do you mean by set it?